# Getting Android Bluetooth Adapter Name from JNI/C++

Tags: android, c++, bluetooth, android-ndk, java-native-interface

The Android API in question is [android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html), which has a member function `getName()` which returns the adapter's user friendly name.

In java: `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getName()`

I know I can wrap this in a java-function, which I call through `jni`, but, how can I achieve the same in `C++`, with only jni/android-ndk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to have permission to read this value (which you would need regardless of it being native).

Add to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

In native `jni`-land, things are a bit cumbersome. In short, this is what you need:

1. Get class `android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter`
2. Get static method `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()`
3. Get method `BluetoothAdapter.getName()`

In order to:

4. Call `2` on `1` to get the default `BluetoothAdapter` instance
5. Call `getName()` on instance from `4.` to get the adapter's name.

This is the same as the java one-liner, just broken down.

---

The code (assuming you already have a `JNIEnv` object):

```cpp
// 1. Get class
// The path matches the package hierarchy of
// 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter'
jclass classBta = env->FindClass("android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter");

// 2. Get id of the static method, getDefaultAdapter()
// Search the web for 'jni function signature' to understand
// the third argument. In short it's a function that takes no arguments,
// hence '()', and returns an object of type
// android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter, which uses syntax "L{path};"
jmethodID methodIdGetAdapter =
    env->GetStaticMethodID(classBta,
                           "getDefaultAdapter",
                           "()Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter;");

// 3. Get id of the non-static method, getName()
// The third argument is the getName function signature,
// no arguments, and returns a java.lang.String object.
jmethodID methodIdGetName =
    env->GetMethodID(classBta,
                     "getName",
                     "()Ljava/lang/String;");

// 4. We get the instance returned by getDefaultAdapter()
jobject objBta = (jobject)
    env->CallStaticObjectMethod(classBta, methodIdGetAdapter);

// 5. Call member method getName on instance
jstring strName = (jstring)
    env->CallObjectMethod(objBta, methodIdGetName);

// Convert jstring to a regular string
const char *result = env->GetStringUTFChars(strName, 0);
std::string blueToothName(result);
```

---

For the sake of clarity, I've omitting sensible checks to see if the various functions have succeeded, and also cleanup:

```
env->DeleteLocalRef(classBta);
env->DeleteLocalRef(objBta);
env->DeleteLocalRef(strName);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(strName, result);
```